# Spring websocket connection closes on network disconnect

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, multithreading, websocket

I am using spring WebSocket on server side and angular client using ng-websocket. So I am using this WebSocket for sending a ping from the client and server respond with pong. This all works fine unless I disconnect my network. So the problem I am facing right now is, particularly on a windows machine. So when network disconnects websocket do not reconnect and the connection gets closed. But when I do the same in Linux machine it reconnects and works fine but on windows, after 10 seconds it disconnects and I got web socket closed on the client side. So I need to know is there any configuration required for WebSocket timeout on windows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some operating systems nuke all connection states when the network disconnects as a way to help applications detect the disconnect and free up resources.  Without this feature, you could technically continue to write to the socket until the buffer fills.  I'm guessing you're on Windows Desktop and not Windows Server.

Comment: Yes, I am using windows desktop not windows server, and should I look for some configuration for windows so that it won't change its state to closed. I have checked the WebSocket state on Linux as well as on windows and it shows open(1) for Linux but closed(3) for windows.  WebSocket state from- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState

Comment: Linux will close the socket eventually. Most notably when Windows returns an RST packet stating it is closed on Windows.  I'd have to spend all day installing Windows Server but, given my history, that it is possible that Win Server and Win Desktop have very different behaviors.  All you need to do is close the connection and open a new one when your ping-pong times out.

Answer (score 0):

Check below link, you should write logic to check periodically and connect.

https://github.com/websockets/ws/wiki/Websocket-client-implementation-for-auto-reconnect

Hope this should help you

Comment: Thanks for the help, it has valuable information on websocket reconnect but I would like to know why is windows websocket closes soon as compare to linux machine.